# Breaking change with Groovy's EqualsAndHashCode annotation

Tags: groovy

There appears to be a breaking change between Groovy 2.4 and 2.5 with the @EqualsAndHashCode annotation behaviour. In 2.4, the 'includes' attribute would allow the inclusion of properties derived from parent classes up the inheritance tree, however, from 2.5 onwards an exception is thrown indicating the inherited field(s) do not exist.

Example code that triggers compilation failure:

This would result in "*The compilation failure is "Error during @EqualsAndHashCode processing: 'includes' property or field 'level0field' does not exist.*"

```
import groovy.transform.EqualsAndHashCode

@EqualsAndHashCode(includes = ['level0field'], includeFields = true)
abstract class Level0 {
  String level0field
}

@EqualsAndHashCode(includes = ['level0field', 'level1field'], callSuper = true, includeFields = true)
class Level1 extends Level0 {
  String level1field
}
```

Has anyone faced this issue and found a workaround aside from writing their own EqualsAndHashCode implementation?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else coming across this problem,  the breaking change was due to stricter checks that simply weren't there prior.  So in 2.4 it would let you get away with listing fields that weren't going to be used in the calculation.

So only include the fields of the owning class in the includes list, and include the attribute "callSuper = true" to go up the object tree.  You can then repeat.